# Can we some how customize the TrackedChange feeds(chatter )?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

Is there is way to customize the text for FeedItem of Type "TrackedChange". I tried creating a trigger on feedItem object doesnt seems to help as the text that comes are not recorded in this object. The Title and body are just blank.

For example..

I have a TrackedChanged feed say "User A changed Status from Active to Inactive". Can we append a text to this ? Using a trigger may be ?